# WordPress: How to set bloginfo parameter values?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

How do I set [WordPress blog_info](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo) parameters to have different values than the defaults?

E.g., I want `<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>` to return `"/stylesheets"`.

Answer (score 1):

In wp-config.php, you can add these lines:

```
define('TEMPLATEPATH', '/stylesheets');
define('STYLESHEETPATH', '/stylesheets');
```

It should work. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

There are two filters toward the bottom of `get_bloginfo`, which should be appropriate.

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.4/wp-includes/general-template.php#L484

`bloginfo` in turn calls `get_bloginfo` so should cover you use.

You can find information on adding/using filters by starting here.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is:

```
   <?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/stylesheets/
```

or

```
<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/path/to/the/folder/stylesheets/
```